# Applying weights to fields for ScoringProfile on a complex object

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, scoring-profile

Hi I'm currently setting up my scoringProfile. I've marked by fields as "IsSearchable" as show below (Notice one field is a complex array).

```
public class MyIndexSchema
{
    [IsSearchable] public int id { get; set; }
    [IsSearchable] public string name { get; set; }
    [IsSearchable] public string keywords { get; set; }
    [IsSearchable] public Category[] category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [IsSearchable] public string type { get; set; }
}
```

The weight I've defined is as below

```
        var fieldWeights = new Dictionary<string, double>
        {
            {"name", 2},
            {"category/type", 1}
        };
```

But when i deploy my solution I'm seeing the following weights in the "Scoring profiles" tab on the selected index, but NOT the Category type field "category/type". What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you retrieve the index definition using the SDK, do you see the weight for category/type? I’m thinking this might be a bug in the portal.

Comment: In addition, if you can provide the name of your search service and index it would be helpful for us to track it down

Comment: Yes i think your correct - Thanks.The bug is in the Portal. The weights were properly applied even though its not showing up in the Portal.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You could write it as a reply to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer easier to be seen by others, I'm posting the answer revealed in comment:

This issue is a bug in the portal.The weights were properly applied even though its not showing up in the Portal.